# Como faço um sistema de excluir e editar os dados do banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Bom, eu fiz um sistema de cadastro de uma videoaula gringa(Estados Unidos), sendo assim eu quero poder editar os dados que esse sistema envia pro banco a partir do código dele, ou seja. Quero fazer um sistema de editar e excluir usando o mesmo código do de cadastro.

Aqui está o código da página de verificação, a que verifica tudo e se estiver tudo certinho, ele envia pro banco.

```
 
    


$data = $_POST;

 session_start();

if (empty($data['nome']) ||
    empty($data['sobrenome']) ||
    empty($data['email']) ||
    empty($data['senha']) ||
    empty($data['repetirsenha'])) {
     $_SESSION['messages'] [] = 'Por Favor preencha todos os campos!';
   header('Location: /create_account'); 
  exit; 
}if ($data['senha'] !== $data['repetirsenha']) {
   $_SESSION['messages'] [] = 'As senhas não estão iguais!';  
   header('Location: /create_account'); 
   exit;
}

 require_once 'config.php';

 $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE nome = :nome OR email = :email');

 if($statement){

   $statement->execute([
 
    ':nome' => $data['nome'],
    ':email' => $data['email'],
 
   ]);

   $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   if(!empty($result)){

    $_SESSION['messages'][] = 'Este email já está cadastrado!';
    header('Location: /create_account');
    exit;

   }

 }

 $statement = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(nome, sobrenome, email, senha, repetirsenha) VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :email, :senha, :repetirsenha)');
 if($statement){
  $result = $statement->execute([
    ':nome' => $data['nome'],
    ':sobrenome' => $data['sobrenome'],
    ':email' => $data['email'],
    ':senha' => $data['senha'],
    ':repetirsenha' => $data['repetirsenha'],
  ]);

   if($result){
    $_SESSION['messages'] [] = 'Bem-Vindo Ao Aquinoflix, Agora você pode desfrutar de um vasto conteúdo de filmes e séries';
    header('Location: /browser');
    exit;
   }

 }
```

Enquanto o formulário, eu já sei como fazer, o problema é mesmo com esse arquivo, que fica responsável por verificar e armazenar os dados no banco. No caso ele teria que virar um de editar e outro de excluir os dados do banco. Se alguém poder pegar o código aqui e já mostrar como fica exatamente eu agradeceria.

Vou deixar aqui o código do arquivo de conexão, config.php, caso alguém queira usar para testar algo ou sei lá.

```
  // Site link geral



// connection with mysqli important!
 $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=install;host=localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $password = '';

 try{

 $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  } catch(PDOException $exception){
     $_SESSION['messages'] [] = 'Connection Failed: ' . $exception->getMessage();
     header('Location: /index.php');
     exit;
  }
```

Comment: Para excluir utilize o comando SQL `DELETE` e para alterar o comando `UPDATE`.

Comment: Então eu só mudo? Mas onde exatamente eu devo colocar, em SELECT ou no lugar do INSERT INTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso queira apenas apagar e editar o usuário os comandos são estes:

Apagar:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE email = :email');
```

Editar:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET nome = :novonome WHERE email = :email');
```